# How to turn on/off the class and member selector in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've probably (accidentally) pressed some keyboard shortcut to hide the class/member bar. I've been searching and clicking through the menu's but can't seem to find a way to show it again. For clarification, this is the bar I'm talking about:

[image: VS bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the main menu:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Uncheck "Navigation bar".

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I expected to find it somewhere in the View menu.